# Hibernate OneToMany table not being updated

Tags: java, hibernate

I have table Animal with OneToMany mapping to table EventAnimal:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "animal")
    public Set<EventAnimal> getEventAnimals() {
        return eventAnimals;
    }
```

Table EventAnimal looks like this

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "eventAnimal")
public class EventAnimal {
    @Id
    int id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userEvent_id")
    UserEvent userEvent;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "animal_id", nullable=false)
    Animal animal;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "eventAnimalClass_id")
    EventAnimalClass eventAnimalClass;
}
```

When I add Event animal to animal and save animal, database is not being updated:

```
        //Create EventAnimal object, set properties
        eventAnimal.setUserEvent(newEvent);
        eventAnimal.setAnimal(animal);
        animal.getEventAnimals().add(eventAnimal);
        animalPersistenceService.saveAnimal(animal);
```

What am I doing wrong?
When I try inserting Event animal, like          `eventAnimalDao.insert(eventAnimal);`
instead of

```
animalPersistenceService.saveAnimal(animal);
```

I get exception that "animal_id" does not have default value even though I set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. It was rather silly mistake - script didn't remove one foreign key from table and I didn't care to look into SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

What is your ID generation strategy? Are you generating the ids by yourself or you will leave this to the DB? If it will be database put:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

You may want to update the key to Integer instead of int too but don`t think this is the problem.

Also if you want to add event in animal and expect to persist it update your mapping to:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "animal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: I tried it, but got Field 'animal_id' doesn't have a default value though animal exists in database and I set it to eventAnimal.

Comment: The snippet on top is from Animal class. It is too big to copy here and take away focus from the problem

Comment: Can you pass the exact exception then? Also did you try storing only the Animal entity without any events? Does it work? Sorry if these questions seems stupid or elementary but I need more information so I can try help better.

Comment: I am not trying to save animal. It is already in database. The exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'animal_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Please can you confirm that you have the id of the Animal entity at the moment of insertion and that id is presented in the DB. That is what the error is stating and either you don`t have the value or either there is problem with mapping the column to the Animal primary key. That is why I wanted to see the Animal class.

Comment: Yes, it is there. Here is primary key of animal:
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have table Company with OneToMany mapping to table Customer:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
private Set<Customer> customer;
```

I have mapped from tis format:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Company
    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="company_id")
private Company company;
```

I have use this code, Sucessfully add,edit and delete function is working.

Add function :

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
Company company = new Company();

company.setCompanyId(intCompanyId);
customer.setCompany(company);
```